# Updating nuget packages via PackageReference in csproj file

Tags: c#, nuget, updating, packagereference

I have a project written with C# with some custom NuGet packages dependencies. 
I want to install the latest version of any package in local repo `.nuget/packages`.
How can I update my dependencies to the latest version automatically? Should I check my local repo and find the latest version of each package during the building? I tried to do something like this: `Version="*"`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: What tooling are you using? In VS, you can use "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." to get an IDE tool to do this for you (click on the "Updates" tab)

Comment: I need to do it without VS. I have to use only local packages and all necessary software (SDK, .NET CORE, etc.)

Comment: `*` is what will tell NuGet to download the latest packages any time it does a full restore. 

When you say, it's not working for you, can you elaborate what specifically is not working?